# change function not working

Tags: 2013, jquery

I have a SP app and one of functions is to change background color but the problem is that when I choose a color in drop down there's nothing happening.

```
<select id ="selectColor">
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
</select>

var opt = $("#selectColor");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectColor").change(function () {
        if ($(this).text == "blue") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing here, `($(this).text == "blue")`. JavaScript is case sensitive, blue != Blue. Either give your options values and evaluate the values, or do a to lower comparison.